# Where does <commandline> <arg> actually look on a Mac/OSX/MACOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, path

Generalist MACOS question.

I'm trying to find the location of an executable I am being told to run. In order to run the file I type:

`postgres -V`

I am sure I have uninstalled this yet it still returns me a 'version'.

I know that if I run a command then the terminal will look in the local folder which I'm in. But the file/executable for `postgres` is not in that folder. What other folders does mac look in?

I know it will use `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` to figure out a list of PATH's but apart from that I am unsure of the process OSX goes to to find executables.

Can anyone shed any light on it? Or point me to documentation? I couldn't find what I wanted when I searched.

Even better can I do some sort of command which tells me the location of that particular executable?

Answer (score 1):

The shell looks through `$PATH` to find the executable. You can see it by issuing this command:

```
echo $PATH
```

You can also use `which` to find where the OS would find an executable (i.e. which one is actually being run):

```
which postgres
```

If that fails, it means your command is an alias or a function, which you could check using `type`:

```
type postgres
```

(`postgres` is typically *not* an alias or a function, this is just for completeness' sake.)

> I know that if I run a command then the terminal will look in the local folder which I'm in

This is true on Windows/DOS. It is typically *not true* on Unix/Linux (including OSX), unless `.` was explicitly added to `$PATH` (which is *not* recommended for security reasons). To start something in the current directory, typically you'd need to explicitly add the folder: `./my_command`.